# Adaptive brightness cannot be disabled in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, laptop, windows-8.1, brightness, display-settings

I am battling with adaptive brightness on my laptop. It just cannot be disabled. I have it turned off in Windows power settings, Intel Graphic Control Panel but without any success. As soon as I switch to some dark application it will quicky dim the display.

My laptop is Toshiba Portege Z30. I have the newest BIOS and drivers are also updated. I found some tips about disabling service for this, but I cannot find anything with "Brightness" in my services list.

Thanks for help, I really makes me mad.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your laptop is equipped with a light sensor.
Have you already tried [this steps](http://acer-au.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/34067/~/enable-or-disable-adaptive-brightness-in-windows-8-and-8.1):

Press the Windows (Image: icon_Windows8_key.png) key + C to open your Charms..

```
Select the Settings charm, and then click Change PC settings..

Tap or click on PC and devices, then select Power and sleep.

Locate Adjust my screen brightness automatically.
```

**If this setting is not present, your device is not equipped with a light sensor.**

```
Tap to slide the slider under this option to On or Off 
depending on your preference.
```

Comment: Yes, but the option isn't present. Brightness is changed based on th conent currently on screen.

Comment: Take a look at this one as well: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/brightness-automatically-adjusts-with-background/316a32e0-7413-4eb0-b80b-fe17b6599920

Comment: Yeah I know about this settings but it has no effect.

Comment: Workaround: cover the light sensor or camera, as the case may be,  with black tape. If it's the camera, put a piece of paper over the center of the sticky tape so adhesive does not smear the lens.